# AngularJS: run block with async service + routeChangeStart to control authentication

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, local-storage, watch

Attempt to perform an angular application with authentication for some urls.

At login, using the login form, via http (service LoginServ, LogIn function) is obtained whether or not the user has permission to access. If allowed to enter, save a token in localStorage, so that the user does not have to reenter your username / password later.

Initially, if the key exists in the localstore not to display the login form. Should be consulted via api http if you continue to have access or revoked (LoginServ.LogInToken service). If you continue routed to the url requested, otherwise the login.

The problem is the call to service (1) which is asynchronous. When run the route change (routeChangeStart) in (3), not yet complete (2), having an incorrect value in isLoggedIn.

What is missing? It is appropriate to the style of the solution? Thanks

App.js

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $ionicLoading, $rootScope, Config, LoginServ) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if (Config.configToken !== "undefined") {
        LoginServ.LogInToken().then(function (json_rta) {
    // => (1) <=
            var acceso      = json_rta.acceso;
            LoginServ.SetLogueo(acceso);
    // => (2) <=
        })
    }

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event) {
    // => (3) <=
        if (!LoginServ.isLoggedIn()) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $location.path('/login');
        }
    });         
  });
})
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $provide) {
    if (
        localStorage.getItem('rm_t') === "undefined" ||
        localStorage.getItem('rm_t') === null
    ) {
        $provide.value('Config', {
            configToken: "undefined",
            configLogin: false
        })
        localStorage.removeItem('rm_t');
    } else {
        $provide.value('Config', {
            configToken: localStorage.getItem('rm_t'),
            configLogin: true
        })
    }    
  $stateProvider
    .state('login', {
      url: "/login",
      templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
      controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    })

    .state('app.ranking', {
        url: "/ranking",
        views: {
            'menuContent' :{
                templateUrl: "templates/ranking/divisiones.html",
                controller: 'RankingDivisionesCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');  
});
```

LogInServ

```
.factory('LoginServ', function ($location, $http, UrlRaiz, Config) {
    var loginAPI    = {};

    loginAPI.SetToken = function(token) {
        Config.configToken = token;
    }

    loginAPI.SetLogueo = function(flagLogin) {
        Config.configLogin = flagLogin;
    }

    loginAPI.isLoggedIn = function() {
        if (Config.configLogin === true) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }   

    loginAPI.LogInToken = function(token) {
        var token           = Config.configToken;

        promise = $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url: UrlRaiz + 'index.php/app/permisos/ingreso_logueado/',
            data: {
                token: token
            }               
        })
        .then(function (response){
            return response.data
        });

        return promise;
    }   

    loginAPI.LogIn = function(datosLogin) {
        var email           = datosLogin.email;
        var clave           = datosLogin.clave;

        return $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url: UrlRaiz + 'index.php/app/permisos/ingreso/',
            data: {
                email: email,
                clave: clave
            }               
        });
    }   

    loginAPI.LogOut = function() {
        Config.configLogin = false;
        localStorage.removeItem('rm_t');
        $location.path("/login");
    }   

    return loginAPI;
});
```

LogInCtrl

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading, $location, LoginServ) {
    LoginServ.LogOut();

     $scope.submitted = false;      

    $scope.LogIn = function(datosLogin) {
        $scope.submitted = true;

        LoginServ.LogIn(datosLogin).success(function (json_rta) {
            var acceso      = json_rta.acceso;

            if (acceso) {
                localStorage.setItem('rm_t', json_rta.token);
                LoginServ.SetToken(json_rta.token);
                LoginServ.SetLogueo(true);
                $location.path("app/ranking");
            } else {
                $scope.login_error = json_rta.error;
            }

        }).error(function (response){
        });
    };      

});
```

A section (app.ranking) that requires authentication to access:

```
.controller('RankingDivisionesCtrl', function($scope, LoginServ, Config) {
    $scope.$watch(LoginServ.isLoggedIn, function (value, oldValue) {
        if (!value && oldValue) {
            $location.path('/login');
        }

        if (value) {
            //Do something when the user is connected
            $scope.divisiones   = {};
        } else {
            LoginServ.LogOut();
        }
  }, true);
});
```

Comment: look into `resolve` property of `$stateProvider` - this will block switching to a view until all resolve properties are resolved, including your async authentiation-related functions

Comment: But I nedd add resolve property in all routes. Any some global? same to preload data before routing?

Comment: You could create a root state for the subtree of states that require authentication, and add the `resolve` there